# Mocking execSync in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

How do I mock out executing a child process in Jest

```js
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
//...
expect(execSync)
  .toHaveBeenCalledWith('npm install');
```

But not actually have it run the npm install during the test.

Answer (score 2):

Can just do something like the following:

```
jest.mock("child_process", () => {
  return {
    execSync: () => "This is a test message"
  };
});
```

Where the return value can be a number, string, object or whatever. It just allows you to override the actual implementation of execsync.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lib mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) with `__mocks__` folder that will hold `child_process` folder which will be loaded by jest automatically.

Just create a file

```
// __mocks__/child_process/index.js

module.exports = {
  execSync: jest.fn()
};
```

that will export a mock implementation of `child_process`.